# JS - Can't use return value of custom object

Tags: javascript, html, vector-graphics

Good day, I seem to be running into a problem on my code. I must be missing something but I just can't find it...
I have at the beginning 2 eventListeners that add and remove keys from the `keysDown array'...

I have a custom object:

```
function Vector(x,y) {
    this.x = x;
    this.y = y;
    this.translate = function(x,y){
         this.x += x;
         this.y += y;
    };
}
```

Then I have a custom function that returns a new Vector object:

```
function Input() {
    var v = new Vector(0,0);
    if(keysDown["w".toCharCode(0)]) {
        v.y = 1;
    } else if (keysDown["s".toCharCode(0)]) {
        v.y = -1;
    }
    return v;
}
```

Then I have a repetitive function that runs at an interval of 60 times per second, and within this I want to translate my vector using the input received:

```
var charPosition = new Vector(5,5);

setInterval(function(){

    var input = Input();
    charPosition.translate(input.x, input.y);

},(1000/60));
```

The input works perfectly when I'm handling it on a seperate `var inputX`, `var inputY` inside the interval function. But as soon as I extract it and create a return type from it, I get no output from it this way.

Here is the entire source for the script:

```
    <script>
    addEventListener("keydown", function(e){
        keysDown[e.keyCode] = true;
    },false);
    addEventListener("keyup", function(e){
        delete keysDown[e.keyCode];
    },false);

    var canvasWidth = 640;
    var canvasHeight = 480;

    var canvas = document.getElementById("canvas");

    var keysDown = {};
    var oldKeysDown = {};

    function Vector(x,y){
        this.x = x;
        this.y = y;

        this.lerp = function(startVector,endVector,percent){
            var v = new Vector();
            v.x = startVector.x + percent * ( endVector.x - startVector.x);
            v.y = startVector.y + percent * ( endVector.y - startVector.y);
            return v;
        };

        this.translate = function(x,y){
            this.x += x;
            this.y += y;
        };

        this.toString = function(){
            return "("+this.x+":"+this.y+")";
        };

        this.set = function(x,y){
            this.x = x;
            this.y = y;
        };

    }

    function Entity(){
        // Instantiate entity variables
        this.position = new Vector();
        this.sprite = new Image();
        this.velocity = new Vector();
        this.entityID = "";
        this.entity = "";

        // Entity update function
        // This is where code-side movement and collision detection should be done.
        this.update = function(){
            this.position.translate(this.velocity.x,this.velocity.y);

            // Detect screen-edge
            if(this.position.x - this.sprite.width / 2 < 0)
            {
                this.position.x = 0+(this.sprite.width/2);
            }
            if(this.position.x + this.sprite.width / 2 > canvasWidth)
            {
                this.position.x = canvasWidth-(this.sprite.width/2);
            }
            if(this.position.y - this.sprite.height / 2 < 0)
            {
                this.position.y = 0+(this.sprite.height/2);
            }
            if(this.position.y + this.sprite.height / 2 > canvasHeight)
            {
                this.position.y = canvasHeight-(this.sprite.height/2);
            }
        };

        this.init = function(elementID)
        {
            this.elementID = elementID;
            this.entity = document.getElementById(this.elementID);
            this.position.x = canvasWidth/2-(char.sprite.width/2);
            this.position.y = canvasHeight/2-(char.sprite.height/2);
            this.entity.style.left = (this.position.x - this.sprite.width/2) + "px";
            this.entity.style.bottom = (this.position.y - this.sprite.height/2)+ "px";
            this.entity.innerHTML = "<img src='" + this.sprite.src + "' alt='0'>";
        };

        // Entity draw method - This ensures that the object on the webpage is updated to the same as the code-values;
        this.draw = function(){
            this.entity.style.left = (this.position.x - this.sprite.width/2) + "px";
            this.entity.style.bottom = (this.position.y - this.sprite.height/2)+ "px";
        };
    }

    function Input(){
        var v = new Vector(0,0);
        if(keysDown['W'.charCodeAt(0)]){
            v.y = 1;
        }else if (keysDown['S'.charCodeAt(0)]){
            v.y = -1;
        }

        if(keysDown['D'.charCodeAt(0)]){
            v.x = 1;
        }else if (keysDown['A'.charCodeAt(0)]){
            v.x = -1;
        }

        return v;
    }

    // Initializing a new character
    var char = new Entity();
    char.sprite.src = "spr_character.png";
    char.init("character");

    // This is where the magic happen, this is set to try and run at 60 frames per second (1000ms/60frames)
    setInterval(function(){
        var inp = Input();

        // Doing console.log(inp.toString()) returns the correct input

        char.position.translate(inp.x,inp.y);

        char.update();
        char.draw();

    },(1000/60));

    </script>
```

Comment: Why is input creating a vector? Just seems weird you use that to pass x and y.

Comment: Never ever put methods into factories.

Comment: Not entirely sure I understand what you mean? @epascarello

Comment: What do you mean by "I get no output from it this way?" As a side note, you could probably make the this.translate function a Vector.prototype.translate function to save memory if you're going to have a lot of vectors.

Comment: So what is exactly failing? Are you not getting x and y from input?

Comment: The return value of Input() returns a Vector, which value is always (0,0), even if a button is held. And noted, will probably change it around, still learning quite a bit, coming from C# to Javascript is quite a change for me.

Comment: The code you show is too small to contain the error. While its not the best style ( some keydown handlers would be better ) it should work basically

Comment: I'll add the entire script to the bottom of the question. Hmm, I tried to sum it up as to where I thought the problem was.

Comment: Well did you check that it is going into the if statements? simple console.log()'s can pinpoint the failure points.

Comment: @epascarello - Just tried the console.log, and it is definitely getting inputs. It seems to be returning input aswell... But the .translate function doesn't work. :-/ If I do the whole input function inside the interval, and write the x and y values to seperate variables and pass it to the translate function, it works perfectly, just not when using my Vector object

Comment: So when you do `this.translate = function(x,y){ console.log(x, y); ...` you see the correct values? after that do you see the correct values for x and y in the current vector? How are you checking the current vector that the values have updated?

Comment: `this.translate = function(xV,yV){ console.log(xV + ":" + yV); this.x += xV; this.y += yV; console.log(this.toString()); };`

This displays if left button is held:

`(-1:0)   (NaN:NaN)  (Undefined:Undefined)` I have no idea where the Undefined is coming from

Answer (score 0):

Seems like I solved the issue by changing function Input() a bit.

From:

```
function Input(){
    var v = new Vector(0,0);
    if(keysDown['W'.charCodeAt(0)]){
        v.y = 1;
    }else if (keysDown['S'.charCodeAt(0)]){
        v.y = -1;
    }

    if(keysDown['D'.charCodeAt(0)]){
        v.x = 1;
    }else if (keysDown['A'.charCodeAt(0)]){
        v.x = -1;
    }

    return v;
}
```

To:

```
function Input(){
    this.v = new Vector(0,0);
    if(keysDown['W'.charCodeAt(0)]){
        this.v.y = 1;
    }else if (keysDown['S'.charCodeAt(0)]){
        this.v.y = -1;
    }

    if(keysDown['D'.charCodeAt(0)]){
        this.v.x = 1;
    }else if (keysDown['A'.charCodeAt(0)]){
        this.v.x = -1;
    }

    return this.v;
}
```

I suppose by using `this.v` instead of `var v` changes things?

What bothers be though is that I can read the output just fine, but it can't use it on the first code.

But that's for another day, for now, I've got it solved!

Thanks everyone for your input :-D :-D